# How to create a for loop in python to access the key values of a dictionary using the characters of a word

Tags: python, function, dictionary, for-loop

So, I have a dictionary of the entire alphabet with the characters as its keys and different numbers between 1-9 as its values.

```
SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES = {
'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4, 'g': 2, 'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j':
8, 'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 10, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't'
: 1, 'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10}
```

What I would like to know is how to, given a word, find the sum of the corresponding key values associated with the keys ie. the characters in the word.

eg

```
abc
```

would yield 7.

I have written the following code

```
def get_word_score(word,n):
    """Assumes the word is correct and calculates the score, will need to handle strings with mixed cases"""
    sum = 0
    word_low = word.lower()
    for i in word_low:
        sum += LETTER_VALUES[i]
    return sum
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: How does this code relate to what you want?

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem?

Comment: Never use the `builtin` like `sum` as your variable name.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are calling the wrong `dictionary`: should it be SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES (assuming it's defined globally above).  Secondly, not sure what's the role of `n` in your function signature? Because it's never been used?!

Alternatively, you can simplify the processing to just use `generator expression` and passing to **`sum`** in one shot:

Be reminded - in Python, a string (word) is also an interable that you can iterate.

LETTER_VALUES is your orig. dictionary.

```
def get_word_score(word):
    return sum(LETTER_VALUES[ch] for ch in word.lower())
    

In [4]: get_word_score("ABBA")
Out[4]: 8

In [5]: get_word_score("Dr")
Out[5]: 3

In [6]: get_word_score('Zoo')
Out[6]: 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct. I just modified your code a little bit, so that you can understand how your code can be improved, as follows:

1. It seems that the functin 'get_word_score' does not need parameter 'n', so I removed it.
2. In get_word_score function, I changed 'LETTER_VALUES' to 'SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES'.
3. I changed variable name `sum` to 'sum_of_val' bacause `sum` is a built-in function as @daniel-hao commented

```
def get_word_score(word):
    """Assumes the word is correct and calculates the score, will need to handle strings with mixed cases"""
    sum_of_val = 0
    word_low = word.lower()
    for i in word_low:
        sum_of_val += SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[i]
    return sum_of_val

SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES = {
'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4, 'g': 2, 'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j':
8, 'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 10, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't'
: 1, 'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10}

result = get_word_score('abc')
print(result)

# 7
```

Comment: Let's not using the `builtin` `sum` as the program variable.

Comment: @DanielHao You're right. I missed the point while modifying the provided code. Thanks.